# ionic Popover view displays behind ionic modal view

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I have this issue whereby if i click on a button, it should display my modal view and when i click on the button on my modal view it should display my ionicpopover. example is in my codepen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNrmXK

This works initially but on second try, the view of the popover displays behind the modal. I have narrowed it down to being that the z-index for the modal-backdrop has a z-index: 10 but i have also put in my popover style for my z-index: 999 though it doesnt seem to help.

Any help provided is deeply appreciated.

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width"> 

    <title>Ionic Popover</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body class="platform-ios" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div class="row bar bar-header">
      <button ng-click="showImagesDetailed()">
        Click Me
      </button >
    </div>

    <script id="image-modal2.html" type="text/ng-template" style="z-index: -1; position: fixed;">
  <div class="modal image-modal transparent" on-swipe-down="closeModal()"> 
  <ion-header-bar class="dark-bg" ng-click="popover.show($event)">
    <div class="buttons buttons-right header-item pull-right">
      <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-android-more-vertical"></button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-slide-box active-slide="activeSlide" >
      <ion-slide>
        <ion-scroll direction="xy" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false" zooming="true" min-zoom="{{zoomMin}}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" delegate-handle="scrollHandle{{$index}}"> 
          <div class="image" style="background-image: url( 'http://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/guidelines-for-placing-your-bird-thinkstock-93216977.jpg')"></div>   
        </ion-scroll>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
  </div>
</script>

    <script id="templates/popover.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-popover-view style="z-index: 999; position: absolute;">
    <ion-content class="light-bg">
      <div class="list light-bg">
        <button class="item light-bg button" ng-click="downloadImage($index, detailedCaseInfo.real_estate_agent_assignment_attachments)">
          <h4>Save</h4>
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-popover-view>
    </script>

  </body>
</html>

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopover, $ionicModal) {


  $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal1.hide();
      $scope.modal1.remove();
  }

  $scope.showImagesDetailed = function() {
    console.log("clicked")

 $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('image-modal2.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
        $scope.modal1 = modal;
        $scope.modal1.show();
      });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      $scope.modal1.remove();
    });
  }
  $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html', {
    scope: $scope,
  }).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey @Kingsley, did you find any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: @pcsantana i believe i did but cant remember,. what issue are you having? is it exactly similar or different? I can help out.

Answer (score 0):

The z-indexes are fine. All I needed to do was add this css.

```
.popover.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It seems related to this issue: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/popover-fails-to-render/10848

Comment: In my case, I had to set the height. I was using it inside a complex shadowDOM and somehow the height became 0.